# Jboss angular deployment

Tags: angular, jboss

I am deploying an angular application in a jboss application server and everything seems to work fine until I hit refresh. Once I hit refresh it says 404 not found error. That's because angular's routing module is routing the url from http://localhost:8080/contextroot/index.html to http://localhost:8080/contextroot/xyz.

I tried searching google for jboss angular deployment, jboss angular nginx configuration etc with no luck.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: There may be something [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) that could help you.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use `useHash:true` as a  second argument in `RouterModule.forRoot()`.

Refer: 
https://angular.io/guide/router#!#browser-url-styles
https://medium.com/wineofbits/angular-2-routing-404-page-not-found-on-refresh-a9a0f5786268

Answer (score 0):

It's not the case of Angular router. It should stay as it is. The problem is with the server configuration. It has to redirect every other (apart from the API ones) GET request to index.html.

You will need to configure static file location as well.

Comment: can you please share some links which explains how to do this configuration. I tried "Jboss static file configuration" and unfortunately the results are not what I am looking for..